# Атрибуты тега в jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Можно ли динамически изменить атрибуты тэга jsx.
Для примера есть код

```
const button = () => {

    return (
    <button
    disabled>
    <button>
    )
}
```

Нужно динамически изменять атрибут disabled .
Что то  типа того

```
const button = () => {
let check = true;

return (
<button
 {check ? disabled : ''}>
<button>
)
```

}

Можно ли как динамиечески менять атрибут disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно.

Вариант первый:

```
function App() {
  const disabled = true;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={disabled}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Вариант второй дату получаем из `props`-а и используем оператор spread

```
if (this.props.disabled) {
  options['disabled'] = 'disabled';
}
return <button {...options}>Click</button>;
```

Вариант третий опять оператор `spread`:

```
function App() {
  const disabled = false;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button {...(disabled ? {disabled:true} : {})}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Вариант четвертый стандартный тернарный оператор:

```
function App() {
  const disabled = true;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={disabled ? 'disabled' : null}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Вариантов может быть очень много это конкретно зависит от ситуации в какой ситуации который вариант может помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ArtemPilipchuk всегда пожалуйста.